# How to inherit a parent class without executing the dunder methods in the parent class?

Tags: python, function, class

I have 2 classes in 2 separate files:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello_world()

    def hello_world(self):
        print('Hello World')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Object removed.')

    def __str__(self):
        print('This is a function.')

from parent import parent

class child(parent):
    def function_1(self):
        print('Do something')

    def function_2(self):
        print('Do something else')

    def main(self):
        child().function_1()
        child().function_2()

child().main()
```

For every child class function called by main(), all parent class methods will be executed once which was unwanted. If I cannot modify parent.py and have to inherit the parent class, are there any ways to prevent the child class from executing the dunder methods?

Comment: `child` shouldn't be a subclass of `parent`. Subclasses are for `IS-A` relationships, not `HAS-A`.

Comment: The fact that you don't want to inherit methods is a red flag that your class relationship is not correct.

Comment: Have you considered to just override the dunder methods and not call the parent methods? How did the ``child.py`` "deleted itself"?

Comment: I think providing an [mre] would be prudent. It looks as if you have a very specific case in mind - generic answers may miss that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It showed 'Exception ignored in:' and 'AttributeError: object has no attribute' and then the program just quit. Inheriting the parent methods was a requirement so I was forced to do this. Does the child automatically call all parent methods or are there any ways to stop it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried making a minimal reproducible example and updated my question. I was actually trying to use Selenium in this program. Although I could not exactly reproduce the error in this example, the error occurred whenever main() tried to call function_1() and function_2(). Hope it helps in clarifying the problem and many thanks for your help.